# How to find target string from source string where target string starts and ends with defined characters in PHP

Tags: php

```
$str_source = "This is item name and this are ||all specifications|| of it";
$str_target = "all specifications";
```

I want to do so I can find target string from source string where target string starts and ends with defined characters (like || in above example). Defined characters will always be same for all source and target strings.

I tried to use strpos but using it I was able to fetch entire string either after first defined character or before last defined character.

Please let me know how I can do this using PHP.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. See comments for the step-by-step explanation.

```
<?php

// Your input string, including another delimited substring.
$str_source = "This is ||item name|| and this are ||all specifications|| of it";

/*
Regexp explanation (from regex101.com):
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group ([^\|]+)
Match a single character not present in the list below [^\|]+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
*/

// preg_match_all() will capture all occurrences of the pattern.
preg_match_all('/\|\|([^\|]+)\|\|/', $str_source, $matches);
// $matches[1] will hold an array of matches, i.e. your substrings.
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Outputs:
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(9) "item name"
[1]=>
string(18) "all specifications"
}

Comment: Note: if you intend to use this in a production environment, then please perform proper error checking. This was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `strpos` function like this:

```php
<?php

$str_source = "This is item name and this are ||all specifications|| of it";
$str_target = "all specifications";
$starts = strpos($str_source, $str_target);
$ends = strlen($str_target);
```

Comment: I think the idea is to find `all specifications` by getting whatever text is between the `||` delimiters.

Comment: @NigelRen, yes you are right